# How to use ProcessBuilder properly

Tags: java, windows, runtime, runtime.exec

I am trying to figure out how to use `ProcessBuilder`. This trivial `dir` does not even work. What am I doing wrong?

```
Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","dir C:\\").start();  
InputStream in = pb.getInputStream();  
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
String line;  
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
    System.out.println(line);  
}
```

The output is only:

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]   (C) Copyright 1985-2001
>   Microsoft Corp.

Comment: Go through the Java World article linked from the [exec tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info). Follow the recommendations and if that does not solve the problem, it will likely provide you with more information to go on.

Comment: I suspect also `new ProcessBuilder("cmd","dir C:\\").start();` should be `new ProcessBuilder("cmd","dir","C:\\").start();`

Comment: @AndrewThompson:Ok but I don't use `Runtime#exec`

Comment: @AndrewThompson:The article is very good!I solved it using `Runtime.exec`!I needed to read I/O streams

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)  You should form that into an answer, enter it and mark it correct.  I might do the same (for the first two parts), but although I had *suspicions* the stream consumption might be the problem, they were no more than suspicions.

Comment: But just to check something I am not sure on.  Please don't use `Runtime.exec()` in place of `ProcessBuilder`.  The only good reason to still use the former is if it is necessary to support JRE versions before 1.5, when the `ProcessBuilder` was introduced.  I doubt that article will ever change though, given the clever title.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "dir")
```

Dir is a command of the shell. /C tells the shell to interpret the parameters.

Comment: +1 for solving pb - @Jim look with "`cmd /?`" command parameters.